# Javascript and web sql insert and update query is not working?

Tags: javascript, web-sql

I'm developing a web app in that ,initially checking user's email is exist or not if it exist means,execute update query else execute insert query

my code

```
 function checkLocalDB(name,pass,auth){
    db.transaction(function (tx) {
      tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM loginUsers WHERE user_Name="'+name+'"', [], function (tx, result) {
        dataset = result.rows;
        if(dataset.length > 0){    
            db.transaction(function (tx) {          
              tx.executeSql("UPDATE loginUsers SET authToken=? WHERE id = '2'", [auth]);
            });
        }else{ 
            var query = 'INSERT INTO loginUsers (user_Name , password , authToken) VALUES ("'+name+'" ,"'+pass+'" , "'+auth+'")';
            dbInteract(query);                                
        }
     });
   });
 }
```

this function is not working ,what wrong with this

Comment: What does `is not working` mean?

Comment: update and insert query not executing

Comment: try changing **dbInteract(query);** to **tx.executeSql(query)**

Comment: i tried that also but its not working

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post, but in case someone else has a similar problem (I came across this thread when i did), here is the issue:

tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM loginUsers WHERE user_Name="'+name+'"', [], function (tx, result) {

SHOULD BE:

tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM loginUsers WHERE user_Name=?', [name], function (tx, result) {

AND this line:

var query = 'INSERT INTO loginUsers (user_Name , password , authToken) VALUES ("'+name+'" ,"'+pass+'" , "'+auth+'")';

SHOULD BE:

var query = 'INSERT INTO loginUsers (user_Name , password , authToken) VALUES (?, ?, ?)', [name, pass, auth];

For what ever reason, they did enter the variable right in the second query.